# View tabs during ctrl-tab in Sublime Text?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

In Windows, when you press <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>Tab</kbd> together, then repeatedly press <kbd>Tab</kbd> while holding down on the <kbd>Alt</kbd>, you see a list of all open windows and you can toggle between them.

In Notepad++ and other editors, you can do the same thing with editor tabs using the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> combo.

**Question:**
Although Sublime Text supports basic <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd>, it doesn't support the ability to view a list of all the tabs while keeping the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> tab held down (as does Notepad++). Is there some plugin that provides this functionality, or an alternate key-combination I'm not aware of?

Comment: Should do this out of the box.

Comment: What version of Sublime Text are you using?

Comment: @FredLoh: I don't think my phrasing was clear enough. I want the ability to *see* a list of all the tabs while keeping the control key held down, Like in Notepad++ or Windows (alt-tab) I've editted the question.

Comment: @scriptHero: ST-3. I've added a version tag for the question.

Comment: This seems not to be solved yet, right? I have the same question for ST-3.2.1

Answer (score 1):

Tabs are just open files, to view a list of your open files View -> Sidebar -> Show Open Files

[image]

Comment: That's very useful/helpful. It's not exactly what I was asking for, but it may be good enough.